# Unable to seperate public from private packages

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, yarnpkg

So I've been using Yarn package manager in my Laravel project to download public javascript libraries like jQuery and bootstrap. My .yarnrc config file has one line to specify the module directory so that all packages are inmideately available.

```
--modules-folder public/components
```

This went perfectly fine till I decided to introduce node-sass to my project which is a backend package.

My problem is that node-sass including all its dependencies end up in my public/components folder. Ideally I'd only use Yarn for my public packages and npm for my backend packages (which would end up in node_modules in my project root). But they both use the same package.json file.

Is there a way to split these package managers? Or am I going about this entirely the wrong way.

Comment: This is a rather odd way of doing things. Not saying that it's good or bad, but it is odd. Usually you'd install everything in `node_modules` (using NPM or Yarn) and bundle them using laravel.mix . The way you're doing things may actually overly bloat your modules folder with dev dependencies of dependent packages.

Comment: You make a very good point, I'm going to do that! If you put your comment into an answer I'll accept it as I think this is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, this is a very odd way to set things up. Typically you would do this:

1. Use a single package manager (NPM or Yarn), because mixing them doesn't usually work well. NPM uses `package-lock.json` and yarn uses `yarn.lock` to determine what package version to download so you may end up with dependency mismatches.
2. Use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to create a package bundle, since you are using Laravel you should use [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix)
3. If necessary you can [extract vendor packages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#vendor-extraction) to create bundles that have a higher chance of hitting the browser cache.
4. You can also use SCSS for your stylesheets

Laravel Mix will ensure that only the minimum required files are actually included in the bundle, in addition sources can be minified and you can also set target browser versions to transpile newer ES 6 syntax into compatible JavaScript.

The main reasons to not put the modules directly in your public folder are:

1. You will need to load them as modules, however IE does not allow that at all.
2. You will end up putting all the dependencies and dev dependencies of those modules in the public folder which is unessesary.

Overall I think it's best practice to compile your assets.